# nth Partial Sum $S(n) = \frac{n - 1}{n + 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given:

> Let:
>   $$S = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a(n)$$
>   be an infinite series such that the nth partial sum is given by:
>   $$S(n) = \frac{(n - 1)}{(n + 1)}$$
>   Find  $a(3)$

$a(1):$

$\hspace{1em}\frac{(1\:-\:1)}{(1\:+\:1)} = \frac{0}{2} = 0$

$a(2):$

$\hspace{1em}\frac{(2\:-\:1)}{(2\:+\:1)} = \frac{1}{3}$

$a(3):$

$\hspace{1em}\frac{(3\:-\:1)}{(3\:+\:1)} = \frac{2}{4} = \left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$

I thought with $\frac{1}2{}$ I was done.

When I entered the result, it was declared wrong.

Given Solution:

> $a(3)​= S(3)​− S(2)$
>
> Hence, $a(3)​=​\frac{1}{2}​−​\frac{1}{3}​=​\frac{1}{6}$.

End given solution.

OK, let's work some $S(n)$'s:

$S(1) = a(1) = 0$

$S(2) = a(1) + a(2) = 0 + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$

$S(3) = a(1) + a(2) + a(3) = 0 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$

Using their formula for $a(3)$: 
$$a(3)​= S(3)​− S(2)$$

$a(3)​= S(3)​− S(2) = \frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6} - \frac{2}{6} = \frac{3}{6}= \left[\frac{1}{2}\right]$

### #

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: $S(n)$ is given both as a sum and as a function of $n$ - it is these two expressions for $S(n)$ which are equal.

Comment: You've mistaken the given formula for S(n), as if it is the formula for a(n). It is S(n) that is (n-1)/(n+1). So S(1) = 0, S(2) = 1/3, S(3) = 1/2.

Comment: So how does that effect the evaluation of a(3) or a(n) for that matter?

Comment: S(n) is the sum of the first n "a values". So a(n) can be found by looking at the difference between S(n-1) and S(n). So a(3) = S(3) - S(2) = 1/2 - 1/3 = 1/6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confuse $a(n)$ with $S(n)$. What is meant by $S(n)$ is
$$
S(n)=a(1)+a(2)+\ldots+a(n-1)+a(n).
$$
With $n$ replaced by $n-1$,
$$
S(n-1)=a(1)+a(2)+\ldots +a(n-2)+a(n-1).
$$
Subtracting, 
$$
a(n)=S(n)-S(n-1). 
$$
So, with the information $S(n)=(n-1)/(n+1)$, we get
$$
a(3)=S(3)-S(2)=(3-1)/(3+1)-(2-1)/(2+1)=2/4-1/3=3/6-2/6=1/6.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear explaination.